# Create a batch file that pulls *.log files from directorys

Tags: batch-file

I have looked on a lot of the questions here and I dont see really what I need. I am trying to create a batch file that pulls 6 log files from 2 different places.

The first place its pulling them from is the C:\ 
Second place is C:\COSS\CossEnterpriseSuite\Exes\

I am wanting it to pull the *.log files and for it to put them in a folder called ERRORLOG on the C:.

If anyone could help me with this it would be great the stress level is raising.

Comment: Look at start -> run -> `cmd /k HELP COPY`.  Make sure to quote your paths if you have spaces in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
xcopy /y C:\*.log C:\ERRORLOG
xcopy /y C:\COSS\CossEnterpriseSuite\Exes\*.log C:\ERRORLOG
```

This will wildcard-copy anything that ends with the .log extension from the directories you mentioned, dropping them in the C:\ERRORLOG directory. The /y switch makes sure it doesn't prompt before overwriting existing files.

Comment: that is amazing if i wanted to tell it to grab certain file names like FileUpdates_InternetUpdate.log and InternetUpdate.log how would something like that be added.

Comment: @Alex, rather than passing wildcards as filenames (the *.log), you would enter the actual filename you wish to copy. That is, xcopy /y foo:\path\to\file\FileUpdates_InternetUpdate.log foo:\destination\log

Comment: thanks so much it asks me if i want to make a directory or a file when i first launch it i guess i will find the code so where it can just make the directory without asking

Comment: Strip the trailing backslash from the directory name (second parameter) perhaps?